# Regex parsing: Replace all links from tag <!DOCTYPE html> to tag <body>

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I want to add a solution for a problem. About a parsing. For example I want to change the section `en` with `br` from `https://MyWebsite.com/en/` as to become `https://MyWebsite.com/br/` for all the links which are between `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<body>`.

**This is how the html code looks now:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<link rel="canonical" href="https://MyWebsite.com/en/the-edge-of-the-ice.html" />
..
"@id": "https://MyWebsite.com/en/my-name-is-prince.html"
..
<meta property="og:url" content="https://MyWebsite.com/en/other-link.html"/>

<body>
```

**The output will be:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<link rel="canonical" href="https://MyWebsite.com/br/the-edge-of-the-ice.html" />
..
"@id": "https://MyWebsite.com/br/my-name-is-prince.html"
..
<meta property="og:url" content="https://MyWebsite.com/br/other-link.html"/>

<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**My Solution**

SEARCH: `(?:.*?<!DOCTYPE html>|\G).*?MyWebsite.com/\Ken(.*?)(?=\.html.*?<body>)`

REPLACE BY: `br\1\3`

- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

So, the Pattern for this king of solution is:

`(?:.*?REGION-START|\G).*?FIND-REGEX\K(.*?)(?=END-REGEX.*?REGION-FINAL)`